# Responsive percentage padding of fixed parent

Tags: html, css, percentage

I'm trying to get a child DIV to have its padding set relative to its fixed parent DIV.

To demonstrate the problem, I've put together a quick JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mdxsegLt/

```css
.top-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  max-height: 12.5%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: green;
}

.padding-percentage {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 30%;
  /*padding: 14px;*/
  padding-top: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fixed">
  <div class="padding-percentage">test</div>
</div>
```

In that example, I'd like the red DIV to be contained entirely within the green, using 20% of the green DIVs height for the padding, not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

First things first... lets drop the ALL CAPS element names.  It's bad practice these days. I think you were overdoing it a bit with your CSS declarations and by NOT nesting the text properly by wrapping it in a span or p tag.  You shouldn't just have floating text that's not wrapped in a p or span tag.  Wrapping it in such tags allows you to further customize like I did in my fiddle.

**UPDATE**

I think I actually get what you're trying to do.

CSS:

```
.top-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: green;
}
.padding-percentage {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red;
}
.padding {
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top-fixed">
  <div class="padding-percentage">
    <p class="padding">TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**LINK TO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/tf2kd40s/2/)

Looks like you needed to adjust the CSS and add a class to the "test" text by tossing it an a p tag.

Check out my fiddle and hope it helps you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I wasn't aware the caps were considered bad practice nowadays. I'll remedy that in the future... If I use a px measurement, then it works fine. The issue appears when I try and use a % for a top padding... If I resize the window, the top bar will shrink as the window becomes smaller, but using a fixed px for the padding will keep the text a fixed amount from the top of the window... I need it to scale and for the padding to decrease as the window gets smaller.